# Is srun needed in a sbatch script for a single node/multicore job?

Tags: slurm

I am running a very common bioinformatic tool/command `bowtie2-build`. It can use multi-threads on a single node (not a MPI type job). I have the following sbatch script (basically):

```
#!/bin/bash

#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=1
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=6
#SBATCH --mem=15G
#SBATCH --time=3:00:00

bowtie2-build --threads $SLURM_CPUS_ON_NODE GRCh38.fa GRCh38
```

I read somewhere that whenever more than one CPUs are requested, `srun` must be used so that the last line above should be `srun bowtie2-build ...`? Is it true? I also learned that, for a MPI job, either `srun` or `mpirun` can be used to launch multiple processes. But I do need clarification on using `srun` in the case of single node with multi-threads. Thanks for any help!

(btw: I equated multi-threads with multi-cores in this particular context).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For same-node computations (multithread, etc.) `srun` is not mandatory but using it offers better control and better feedback from Slurm.

If your program is started with `srun`, it will be easier for Slurm to manage it (send UNIX signals, kill it if it uses more resource than requested, etc.), and the `sstat` command will be able to provide you with near-real time memory usage, CPU efficiency, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, helped a lot!